Why is my C #define expression returning different numbers given the same input?
I was running the following C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#define MULTIPLY(x, y) x * y + 2

int main() {
    int result = MULTIPLY(6 - 1, 4);
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}

Logically, I would think it would print 22, however it actually prints 4. I also tested the line
int result= MULTIPLY(5,4);, which actually prints 22. So I am wondering why it is the case that it prints a completely different result for 6-1.

MULTIPLY(6 - 1, 4) expands to  6 - 1 * 4 + 2

An example just like this is usually present and explained in any beginner-level C book so that's the first place to search for the answer.

@Wiimm And the macro as a whole.  Don't use what you showed.  Instead, it should be #define MULTIPLY(x, y) ((x) * (y) + 2).  Without the outer parens, consider what 2*MULTIPLY(3, 4) would do.

Use #define MULTIPLY(x, y) ((x) * (y) + 2) to get the expected result. In general, it is a good idea to use parentheses around macro parameters and around the whole expression.

@TomKarzes Yes, you are right. Usually I add parentheses around the whole expression. But I I forgot to tell. Fixed.

Macros do not return.  THey only replace strings. So x is being replace with 6-1 without evaluation
